# Culebra tester error: No module named culebratester_client.api.default_api

Tags: python, android

When I am running `python gfxinfo2.py com.android.systemui` from [this link](https://medium.com/@dtmilano/analyzing-android-ui-performance-52beb577c421)

I am getting the following message Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "gfxinfo2.py", line 13, in from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient File "D:\Softwares\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 25, in from culebratester_client import WindowHierarchyChild, WindowHierarchy File "D:\Softwares\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\culebratester_client__init__.py", line 18, in from culebratester_client.api.default_api import DefaultApi ImportError: No module named culebratester_client.api.default_api

I am a newbie and don't know much about android and how it works. I need to understand how this works. Kindly help me out. What am I doing wrong over here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [culebratester-client](https://pypi.org/project/culebratester-client/)

```
   pip install culebratester-client
```